# Prevent refreshing Kendo Grid when filter is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a javascript method that refresh Kendo Grid in every 5 seconds and I want to prevent this function not workk when Filter dialog is open or filtering is active. Is it possible? Is there any event that can be used if the filter is active?

```
//For refreshing grid periodically
$(document).ready(function () {
    var refreshId = setInterval(function () {
        var grid = $("#eventGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        $("#eventGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Try binidng setInterval with refresh on grid `dataBound` event and then clear it on `filterMenuInit` event then on close of filter menu (i think that you'll have to make custom event for this) again bind refresh on grid `dataBound` and refresh manually. [docs for filterMenuInit](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-filterMenuInit)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Could you post an example as an answer?

Comment: Maybe later, right now I'm quite busy. But you can dynamically bind event handlers to grid with: `grid.bind('dataBound' , addRefreshToGrid)` and later remove them with `grid.unbind('dataBound' , addRefreshToGrid)`, `addRefreshToGrid` is a handler function reference. To all other events you attach handlers in same fashion. gl

Comment: @Drops Thanks a lot, but I really cannot solve the problem. If you have time could you pls a look at and post a sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that using `.k-animation-container` instead of `.k-filter-menu` for custom filter menus will probably trigger on some other kendo widgets (I think dropdown menu is one of them) so watch out for that.

For default filter menus `.k-animation-container .k-filter-menu` will do the job. For custom filters maybe go with some custom hook/selector, like `.k-animation-container .custom-filter-menu` and then check if it's visible.

```
$(function(){
    var grid = $("#grid").data('kendoGrid'),
        gridRefresh = setInterval(refreshGrid, 5000),
        filterCheck;

    grid.bind('filterMenuInit', onFilterMenuInit);

    function onFilterMenuInit(){
        // console.log('Filter Menu opened');
        // console.log('Grid Refresh removed');
        clearInterval(gridRefresh);
        // console.log('Filter Check added');
        filterCheck = setInterval(filterInterval, 1000);
    }

    function refreshGrid(){
        //console.log('Grid Refreshed');
        grid.dataSource.read();
    }

    function filterInterval(){
        // console.log('Filter Check');
        //    '.k-animation-container .k-filter-menu' for default menus
        // or '.k-animation-container .custom-filter-menu' for custom menus
        if(!$('.k-animation-container').is(":visible")){
            // console.log('Filter Check removed');
            clearInterval(filterCheck);
            // console.log('Grid Refresh added');
            gridRefresh = setInterval(refreshGrid, 5000);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Voted+ But, it only works good on date filters (DateTimePicker), not on the filters of text fields. How to fix it?

Comment: I don't know, at my local grid it worked on every filter, but again I'm using default filter options, not custom, maybe that's issue. But in general, from here, to cover custom filter menus, you can create custom `onFilterMenuInit` implementation to check if `$('.k-animation-container').is(":visible")` at all. That way you'll always get notified if filter menu is opened. Just make similar function like `filterInterval` in my answer to do that for you.

Comment: That is perfect :) After changing `.k-filter-menu` to `.k-animation-container` in the `filterInterval()` method it works on every filter. You might update this so that other people also use it properly. Many thanks again, Voted+++

Answer (score 1):

A different approach - but not sure how reliable it is - is to check the DOM element of the filter. The filter popup is created in the same parent of the grid wrappers, not inside it. So you can check for its element and if it is visible.

With these selectors you can check for the filter popup element:

```
$(grid.element).parent().find(".k-animation-container:visible .k-filter-menu");
```

If any element is returned, then the filter is opened. Check out [this demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ozAYi) (and take a look in the console).